# Deforming a contour in complex contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

If there are no singularities (poles) in the way, and I am integrating a holomorphic function is it legit to deform a contour in such a way that it would change even change quadrant. For example, if my integration contour is $-i \infty$ to $e^{i\pi/6}\infty$, can I ignore the "escape" direction and integrate instead from $-i \infty$ to $+i \infty$?

By extension, if there are no singularities and we are dealing with a holomorphic function, integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the path doesn't matter to determine the value of the integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-i\infty}^{a \infty} f(z)dz = \int_{-i\infty}^{b \infty} f(z)dz \qquad \text{iff} \qquad \lim_{R \to + \infty} \int_{a R}^{bR} f(z)dz =\int_{a\infty}^{b \infty} f(z)dz = 0$$

If you think about it a bit, you'll see we are defining an analytic antiderivative $\displaystyle F(z) = \int_{z_0}^z f(s)ds$ (if $f$ is analytic on $U$ simply connected then so is $F$)  and we are asking if $F$ is continuous at $\infty$ in some sense. For example with $f(z) = e^{-z}$ then $F(z) = e^{-z}-1$ is continuous at the $\infty$ of $U = \{ z \in \mathbb{C},\Re(z) \ge \epsilon > 0\}$ so it makes sense to see it as single point. But the infinities of $\Re(z) \le 0$ are different and $\lim_{|z| \to \infty, \Re(z) \le 0} F(z)$ diverges.